# Custom swipe to delete horizontal button in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I have managed to implement these two button which is native provided by iOS using `editActionsForRowAt` method but I need following output. Anyone help me how do I do this?

[image]

Following is the code I tried

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let accept = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { action, index in
        print("accept button tapped")
        self.animateAvailabilityHideShow(isHide: false, duration: 0.3)
    }
    accept.backgroundColor = UIColor().themeGreenColor

    let reject = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        print("reject button tapped")
    }
    reject.backgroundColor = UIColor().themeRedColor

    return [reject, accept]
}
```

Comment: There is no default option available to have a horizontal swipe for the rowActions. You will need to make a custom one in this case.

Comment: @RakshithNandish I know there's no default option that's why I am asking how to achieve this.

Comment: This will not possilble by using editActionsForRowAt. We can write own code for this. Bcos, editActionsForRowAt this will work on row height. So default behaviour vertical.

Comment: Havent tried any such implementation. What you can try is have a scroll view in the cell and increase and decrease the offset for the buttons as he scrolls. Then again this design seems odd and is not encouraged.